# How get a space values between every chars?

Tags: xetex

Is possible to write to file all information of chapter with spaces, lines and chars?

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [bankfotek.pl](http://bankfotek.pl/image/1830603.jpeg))</sub>

I have text, and 5cm wide line. I need ascii text file with

```
Śród (space x1) takich (space x2) pól (x3) przed (x4)  laty(x5),(x6) 

nad (x7) brzegiem (x8) ruczaju,(x9) Na(x10)

pagórku () niewielkim,() we () br()-

zozowym gaju, .....
```

I need characters and space and next character space ...
I need convert it back to tex with my own kerning.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\begin{document}
\parbox{5cm}{Śród takich pól przed laty, nad brzegiem ruczaju,
Na pagórku niewielkim, we brzozowym gaju,
Stał dwór szlachecki, z drzewa, lecz podmurowany;
Świeciły się z daleka pobielane ściany,
Tym bielsze, że odbite od ciemnej zieleni}
\end{document}
```

http://bankfotek.pl/image/1833810

Comment: See the package http://ctan.org/pkg/lua-visual-debug - it analyzes the box at shipout.

Answer (score 5):

You can obtain this information from the log with a bit of effort.

```
\documentclass{article}

\showoutput

\begin{document}

One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.


\end{document}
```

[image]

produces a log which for the first line says

```
...\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x345.0, glue set - 0.0698
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 O
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 n
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
....\kern-0.27779
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 w
....\kern-0.27779
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 o
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 h
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 r
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
```

which shows (if you read it vertically) each character set from which font, and the inter-word spaces. they are shown as input with stretch and shrink component but you can 
work out the actual size from the start of the box withe the `glue set` factor, here 
`glue set - 0.0698` so each glue with a finite shrink component was shrunk by that proportion of its shrink component.

the next line looks similar, and the third line has

```
...\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x345.0, glue set 0.08626
```

with a positive glue set ratio, so in this case the stretch component of the inter word glue was used.

The final line has infinite glue:

```
...\hbox(6.67859+0.0)x345.0, glue set 306.6666fil
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 n
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 i
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 n
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 n
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 .
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
..\glue(\baselineskip) 23.55556
..\hbox(6.44444+0.0)x345.0, glue set 170.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
```

where the glue set now tells you that each `1fil` worth of glue is that many `pt`. In this case all coming from `\parfillskip` to complete the short line after the final two words.

Comment: Very complicated. Is a easy form. Meybe LuaLatex? I need convert it back to tex with my own kerning. log have only 3-4 digit after dot.

Comment: @bardzo perhaps you should ask a new question with your actual requirement, there are lots of ways to control the inter-word space without writing anything out to a file

Comment: I write to ascii file ;-D yes.